# The authenticity of host github.com 192.30.253.112 can't be established while installing feathers-rest/client

Tags: github, npm, feathersjs

I'm running this:

```
npm install --save feathers-rest/client
```

and getting this:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
```

I can add that the error only occurs for this particular module: feathers-rest/client. I have installed many others with success.

So I guess the error must be related to this module.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can add that I found out that feathers-rest/client is really not a NPM module. feathers-rest is the NPM-module and client is a subfolder under it. So I guess the error is related to this. It is still a very strange error message though.

Comment: As you pointed out, `feathers-rest` is the correct module. To my knowledge it doesn't install any Git dependencies though so I'm not sure where that error is coming from.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a problem with feathers-rest/client. This is normal behavior of your SSH client, which will ask you to confirm because it does not yet know the SSH key fingerprint for GitHub the first time you connect.

It looks like your connection was fine, you can compare the fingerprint to the ones that GitHub has posted here  https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints/ to ensure you are not a victim of a [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Once you type 'yes' once, it should save that fingerprint locally and not ask again.

Comment: Thx for the hint. Will try it out next time I get a similar problem.